# Creating text files with %d id in c

Tags: c, file-io

I was wondering how can I create a text file like this:

For example if I have:

```
FILE *f;
int id=1;
f = fopen("file\%d.txt", "a");
```

In the end of file I would like to add the number of the id. I tried several things but nothing worked.

Comment: What exactly did you try and how exactly did it not work?

Comment: You are looking for `sprintf` as Unwind mentions in his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fail to show what you actually tried.

The typical solution is to use `sprintf()`:

```
char fnbuf[1024];
int a = 1;
sprintf(fnbuf, "file%d.txt", a);
f = fopen(fnbuf, "a");
```

Note that this is pretty safe, but in a real program with more complexity it's a good idea to use [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf), and of course to check the return values.